# What is the workflow of Spring Cloud Contracts?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I've been searching a lot online but I haven't found any clear answer to this. So far my understanding is this:

1. Consumer writes a contract for every provider manually (perhaps they add versioning for the contracts?)
2. Consumer shares the contract with the provider
3. Provider uses the Spring Cloud Contract Verifier dependency and plugin to generate several test files
4. Provider runs the test files against their service and generates a test result
5. Provider generates a single stub file by running the tests
6. Provider shares the latest stub file + test results back with the consumer
7. Consumer takes the stub file + Spring Cloud Contract Stub Runner to create a mock service of the provider
8. Consumer runs the contract on their own service + mock service of provider
9. The union of the results (consumer + provider) are taken together by the consumer to decide if they're good to release their service

Are these the correct sequence of events?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the reference documentation of Spring Cloud Contract https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using where you can find graphs of all the workflows for different contract test types.